# io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl uses tomcat classes instead of self

Tags: java, tomcat, netty, grpc

Trying to use netty-tcnative-boringssl-static under tomcat. When lunching code from JUnit test it works properly, but not so in the tomcat container.
This code in the io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl class is trying to load native library from class loader of SSL class.

```
private static void loadTcNative() throws Exception {
    String os = normalizeOs(SystemPropertyUtil.get("os.name", ""));
    String arch = normalizeArch(SystemPropertyUtil.get("os.arch", ""));

    Set<String> libNames = new LinkedHashSet<String>(3);
    // First, try loading the platform-specific library. Platform-specific
    // libraries will be available if using a tcnative uber jar.
    libNames.add("netty-tcnative-" + os + '-' + arch);
    if (LINUX.equalsIgnoreCase(os)) {
        // Fedora SSL lib so naming (libssl.so.10 vs libssl.so.1.0.0)..
        libNames.add("netty-tcnative-" + os + '-' + arch + "-fedora");
    }
    // finally the default library.
    libNames.add("netty-tcnative");

    NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(SSL.class.getClassLoader(),
        libNames.toArray(new String[libNames.size()]));
}
```

When it works separately (e.g. from JUnit test) it's finding SSL class in netty-tcnative-boringssl-static jar and getting native library from it from WEB-INF/native in those jar dependency.
But when it works under tomcat it's getting SSL class from tomcat library and can't find native library.

Tried with tomcat 8 and 9

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed shortly and be part of 4.1.9.Final:

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/5766

Comment: I just spent 2 days on this.
google-cloud-logging 1.0.2 relies on 4.1.8 and brought me here.
forcing 4.1.9+ via maven solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if found the solution in this thread 
https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/136

I've just copied netty-tcnative-boringssl-static.jar and relinked tomcat-jni.jar to it in tomcat library directory